# Abnormal height of UIView in autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, autolayout

I have added a UIView with height of 2px in a VC in storyboard. Without auto layout it appears exactly as storyboard in simulator. But if i use autolayout then this sub view appears with abnormal height like 50px-60px height. Why ?

[Simulator Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1suh72ckpla6ike/Screenshot%202015-03-09%2018.02.14.png?dl=0)

[Storyboard Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbr4hvy2h0xbnpt/Screenshot%202015-03-09%2018.02.36.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of auto-layout. That view has 4 constraints. Trailing space to superview and leading space to superview are sides of the view.
Bottom space and top space are as you guessed bottom and top and since simulator has different size than your storyboard view it adjust height of your view to fit these constraints and be 46 from top and  439 from bottom.

What you need to do if you want to keep your view height at 2px is to set height constraint instead of the bottom layout constraint.

Comment: Sorry to late reply. How do i set height constraint instead of the bottom layout constraint ?

Comment: Okay i did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below 4 Constrains to that UIView,

```
Leading Space to Container -> Main UIView
Trailing Space to Container -> Main UIView
Top Space to Container -> Main UIView
UIView Height Container 2px
```